# binding LINQ Query on post back has rows but doesn't display on screen

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, binding

I have a gridview that I bind using a LINQ query, initialy it binds perfect, but on post back, post backs triggers, linq query code runs perfect and generates rows. I explicitly assign the result as datasourcce and  bind the gridview( same query used for initial binding) ,. Checked for rows in the gridview during debugging, has rows, but it doesn't display it onscreen. any help please?

below is the code behind

```
var tl = (from i in dbcontex.SelectionProcesses
                  where i.VA.Position.Section.Contains( cmbSecs.SelectedValue) &&
                  i.VA.Position.DutyStation.Contains(cmbDutyS.SelectedValue) &&
                  i.VA.Position.Status != "Filled"
                  select new
                  {
                      i.VANo,
                      i.VA.Position.Level,
                      i.VA.ClosingDate,
                      i.TimeLine.NumAllottedDays,
                      DateOfferGiven=i.DateOfferGiven.Value==null?DateTime.MinValue:i.DateOfferGiven.Value,
                      DateApproved= i.DateApproved.Value==null?DateTime.MinValue:i.DateApproved.Value,
                      DateApprovedByRep = i.DateApprovedByRep.Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : i.DateApprovedByRep.Value,
                      DateCRBConducted = i.DateCRBConducted.Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : i.DateCRBConducted.Value,
                      DateCBIConducted = i.DateCBIConducted.Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : i.DateCBIConducted.Value,
                      DateFinalShortReceived = i.DateFinalShortReceived.Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : i.DateFinalShortReceived.Value,
                      DatePrescreenedCVSent = i.DatePrescreenedCVSent.Value == null ? DateTime.MinValue : i.DatePrescreenedCVSent.Value


                  }).ToList().
                 Select(l => new
                         {
                             l.VANo,
                             l.Level,
                             ClosingDate = l.ClosingDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
                             PreScreen =l.DatePrescreenedCVSent>l.ClosingDate?(l.DatePrescreenedCVSent - l.ClosingDate).Duration().Days:0,
                             ShortListing = l.DateFinalShortReceived>l.DatePrescreenedCVSent?(l.DateFinalShortReceived - l.DatePrescreenedCVSent).Duration().Days:0,
                             CBI = l.DateCBIConducted>l.DateFinalShortReceived?(l.DateCBIConducted - l.DateFinalShortReceived).Duration().Days:0,
                             RepApproval = l.DateApprovedByRep>l.DateCRBConducted?(l.DateApprovedByRep - l.DateCRBConducted).Duration().Days:0,
                             ESARDHR = !l.Level.Contains("GS") || l.DateApprovedByRep>l.DateApproved ? 0  : (l.DateApproved - l.DateApprovedByRep).Duration().Days,
                             Offer = l.DateOfferGiven>l.DateApproved ?(l.DateOfferGiven - l.DateApproved).Duration().Days:0,
                             TotalAllowed = l.NumAllottedDays
                         }).ToList().
                         Select(i => new
                         {
                             i.VANo,
                             i.Level,
                             i.ClosingDate,
                             i.PreScreen,
                             i.ShortListing,
                             i.CBI,
                             i.RepApproval,
                             i.ESARDHR,
                             i.Offer,
                             i.TotalAllowed,
                             TotalDaysTaken=i.PreScreen+i.ShortListing+i.CBI+i.RepApproval+i.Offer+i.ESARDHR
                         }
                         ).OrderBy(l => l.Level);
        var x = tl;
        gvTimeLine.DataSource = x;
        gvTimeLine.DataBind();
        if (gvTimeLine.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvTimeLine.SelectedIndex = 0;
            gvTimeLine_SelectedIndexChanged(this, GridViewSelectEventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

the html

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gvTimeLine" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                Caption="List of Recruitment Time Lines Showing days taken" 
                CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333"  Width="100%" 
                onrowdatabound="gvTimeLine_RowDataBound"  GridLines="Vertical"
                EmptyDataText="No Recruitment is underway" 
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                DataKeyNames="VANo" 
                onselectedindexchanged="gvTimeLine_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                style="margin-top: 0px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VA/ReqNo">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hplk" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"  
                         Text='<%# Bind("VANo") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Level" HeaderText ="Level" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClosingDate" HeaderText ="Closing Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PreScreen" HeaderText ="Prescreen" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortListing" HeaderText ="Short Listing" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CBI" HeaderText ="CBI" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RepApproval" HeaderText ="Rep Approval" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ESARDHR" HeaderText ="ESAR/DHR" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Offer" HeaderText ="Offer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAllowed" HeaderText ="Total Days 
                  Allowed" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalDaysTaken" HeaderText ="Total Days 
                 Taken" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="TimeLine">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <eo:ProgressBar ID="prgStatus" ControlSkinID="None" Width="68px" 
                        runat="server" Height="16px" BackColor="#C7C7C7">
                </eo:ProgressBar>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

          </Asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: We need to see your code to be able to help.

Comment: have added the code behind on the post.., the *.aspx page has a gridview with autogeneratecolumns set to  false and that is coz  i have customized the columns

Comment: Not very sure if this will solve the problem but did you try gvTimeLine.DataSource = x.ToList();? Also can you post the html for the gridview?

Comment: Samar, theans for the suggestion, but you know the query was bound perferctly initially , but during post back it does generate the result, but Gridview doesn't show

Comment: hello guys!, any workaround..., I couldn't resolve this so far

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the datasource before you bind any new data. The following code will clear any existing data. unless of course the problem is that the DataSource you are assigning has the duplicated data.

```
gridview.DataSource = null;
gridview.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps. If it doesnt then please comment.

Comment: actually, I have done that, but that didn't solve it

Comment: Any help on the above problem,... please

Comment: On what event are you performing the post back? Also can you show the entire event code which contains the above LINQ query? I am gussing it is `Page_Load` event.